# ValidationSummary style not displaying in IE 6 on Post asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-6, customvalidator, validationsummary

I am posting back to the server to check the DB to see if we hold a reference number. If the reference number does not exist I set two custom validators to invalid and change the ValidationSummary header text. The problem is that the background colour I set in the css class does not display. The font colour does display correctly.

When the validation summary is displayed using client side script the styles are displayed correctly. i am not sure why they dont when there is a post back.

css

```
.form-box .form-error-box {
    background: #cd3300 url("../../../images/alert.gif") no-repeat 10px 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px;
    padding-left: 80px;
    min-height:55px;
}
```

code

```
<asp:validationsummary id="vSummary" cssclass="form-error-box" displaymode="BulletList" headertext="An error has occured" runat="server" backcolor="" forecolor="" />
```

This works in Firefox and IE 8 on post but not IE 6. Unfortunatly I have to support IE 6

Comment: please add rendered code from view source for validation summery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to add a height to the ValidationSummary div in IE6. I am not sure why this only happens on postback. I think it has something to do with the IE6 auto-expansion bug [IE6 bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/expandingboxbug.html)

Add the following in your page or masterpag to include an IE6 specific stylesheet:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/system/ie-form.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

ie-form stylesheet code:

```
.form-error-box {
    height:75px;
}
```

another tip is to add `forecolor=""` to the ValidationSummary control to remove asp.net default red font color.